# How to use read files in node.js that have a slash in the name.

Tags: javascript, node.js

So i am trying to read a file that has this name 'TinyMCE3x/Installation'

```
var filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../tiny-mce/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x/Installation');
```

What happens now is that path tries to locate a file called 'Installation' inside a folder called 'TinyMCE3x' while i want it to look for a file called 'TinyMCE3x/Installation'. I am sure its a simple escaping thing i am missing here. Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Don't know which OS and filesystem you have, but I wouldn't use filename with /. In most platforms its not even possible, and it will surely cause lots of unexpected problems. If possible, consider changing the filename so it won't contain any slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your OS but this trick always saves me

```
const filename = 'try/catch.txt'.replace('/', '\u2215');
require('fs').writeFileSync(filename);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use escape character `\`

```
var filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../tiny-mce/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x\/Installation');
```

Comment: tried that. Dosen't work. Still complains file does not exist.